# How to save the value of a range slider (multiple input form) in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a range slider as a one file of my form. I can update the value of the item with js.
Sending the checkboxes state works, however, for some reason I cannot get range slider value.

Here's my template:

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table id="levels">
        <label class="container">Easy
        <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="1">
        <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <!--you get the idea-->
    </table>
     <input type="range" min="1" max="120" value="120" class="form-control-range" id="time_slider">
    <b> <span id="slider_value" ></span></b> min.
<input type="submit" id="update" name = "update" value="Filter">
</form>
<script>
        var slider = document.getElementById("time_slider");
        var output = document.getElementById("slider_value");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;
        slider.oninput = function() {
            output.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
    </script>
```

and my view.py:

```py
def item_list(request):

    items = Items.objects.all()

    if request.POST:
        if 'update' in request.POST:
            check_list = request.POST.getlist('checks')
            time = request.POST.get('slider_value')
            if check_list:
                items=items.filter(level__in=check_list)
            if time:
                items=items.filter(time__lte=time)
```

If I print the *check_list* there are all the checkboxes I tick. The slider is responsive, script works but no value is send to my view. All I get is "None". Switching get to *time_slider* is not helping either. What I did wrong?

Comment: your form doesn't have any input with `name="slider_value"`, so this will never be in the POST data. Did you just forget to put that attribute on the `input type="range"`?

Comment: Your checkboxes have a `name` attribute. Your slider doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. I was clueless and as you can see front-end is not my forte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your range input a name attribute. Since you are already checking for **slider_valu** in your backend code, then you can change your code to be this:

```
<input name="slider_value" type="range" min="1" max="120" value="120" class="form-control-range" id="time_slider">
```